# What exactly is this function doing?

Tags: abstract-algebra

For a set S define the natural isomorphism Char: P(S) → F(S, {0, 1}).

Let A be a subset of S. if x is an element of A, then it goes to 1, if it isn't, it goes to 0.

I drew a diagram on a paper to try to get a bigger understanding and larger picture of what's happening, but I just don't get it. I guess I think I can see that it's an isomorphism because the powerset of S has the same number of elements as the set of functions that go from subset of S to the element 1 but even this thought isn't fully secure in my head. But to be honest, I feel like this isomorphism is being forced to show something or to be used in someway. What way is that?

Edit: Actually, how many functions Can go from a Set to two elements? I think I kind of assumed that since the domain is the powerset, it maps any subset whatsoever to the codomain, which is the set of all functions that go from a subset of S to {0,1}, which will be 1. So they do have the same cardinality in my head, but I'm still not too sure

Comment: One common use of the characteristic function is to write piecewise functions in a nicer way. For instance, if $A \cap B = \emptyset$ and $$f(x) = \begin{cases} g(x), &x \in A;\\ h(x), &x \in B;\\ 0, &\text{otherwise;} \end{cases}$$
then you can also write this as $f(x) = g(x)\mathbb{I}_A(x) + h(x) \mathbb{I}_B(x)$, where $\mathbb{I}$ denotes the indicator (or characteristic) function.

Comment: See for example [Indicator function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function)

Comment: P(S) -> F(S -> {0,1}    Is it understood that the subset you choose from the powerset isn't the same subset you choose from the otherside 'F(S -> {0,1}) ' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example which might clarify the situation.

Let $S = \{a,b,c\}$. This is our starting point.

Next, we form $\mathcal{P}(S)$, the set of all subsets of $S$. Explicitly:

$\mathcal{P}(S) = \{\emptyset, \{a\},\{b\},\{c\},\{a,b\},\{a,c\},\{b,c\},S\}$

Now let's look at $\text{Char}(A)$, for some sets $A \in \mathcal{P}(S)$.

Some easy ones:

$\text{Char}(\emptyset)$ is the following function:

$f:S \to \{0,1\}$ given by $f(s) = 0$ for all $s \in S$. Since the empty set has no elements, $f(s)$ is never $1$, so it is always $0$.

The other "obvious one" is $\text{Char}(S)$ which is the function:

$g:S \to \{0,1\}$ given by $g(s) = 1$ for all $s \in S$ -it's all $1$'s, since every $s \in S$ is in $S$.

Ok, so now let's look at a "less obvious" subset, say $A = \{a,b\}$. Which function might $\text{Char}(A)$ be? Let's call it $h$ for now.

$a \in A$, so $h(a) = 1$.

$b \in A$, so $h(b) = 1$.

$c \not\in A$, so $h(c) = 0$. So this is $h$:

$a \mapsto 1$

$b \mapsto 1$

$c \mapsto 0$.

For every possible domain element $s \in S$, we have $2$ choices of image for our "possible function" $S \to \{0,1\}$. Having chosen this for $a$, we have two such choices for $b$, and having chosen this, we have two choices for where to map $c$, giving us:
$2\cdot2\cdot2 = 8$ possible functions we can have. Strangely enough, there are $8$ possible subsets of $S$, that is $8$ elements in $\mathcal{P}(S)$.

Comment: MAkes it crystal clear. Thank you, man!

Comment: The powerset has 2^n elements, and this set seems to have 2^n elements as well. That seems like that is supposed to be the case. It's pretty cleverly constructed it seems

Answer (score 2):

Let us call this characteristic function by $\mathbb{1}$. Now $\mathbb{1}$ is a function from the power set of $S$ to $[S\rightarrow \{0,1\}]$ --- the set of functions from $S$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Therefore we might write $\mathbb{1}:\mathcal{P}(S)\rightarrow [S\rightarrow\{0,1\}]$, and the way it works is that the set $A\in\mathcal{P}(s)$ is sent to the function $\mathbb{1}_A$. This could be written as $A\mapsto \mathbb{1}_A$ or even $\mathbb{1}(A)=\mathbb{1}_A$ if you like the whole '$f(x)$' thing.

Now $\mathbb{1}_A\in[S\rightarrow\{0,1\}]$ and as you said this is defined by

$$\mathbb{1}_A(x)=\begin{cases}1 & \text{ if }x\in A\\ 0 & \text{ if }x\not\in A\end{cases}$$

...imagine your set $S$... now imagine a subset $A\subset S$. $\mathbb{1}_A$ 'paints' elements of $S$ --- black ($1$) if there are in $A$ or white ($0$) if they are not in $A$.

Comment: The set of functions that goes from our set A to {0,1} is one right? Why is the {0} in the set if things will automatically get mapped to 1 by this definition?

Comment: The Way I imagine it in my head is like this: You have the powerset of a Set called 'S'. Now, this function takes any element of this powerset -- which is all possible subsets of our set S-- and sends it to a set of functions. This set of functions goes from our set A into '0' or '1' depending on whether an element of x is in A. But shouldn't elements automatically be in A if this function operates on the set A?

Comment: Each subset $ A$ is mapped to one function $1_A $. The function $1_A $ tells you whether its input is in $ A$.

Comment: No each subset is mapped to ONE function. Like Ian said.

Comment: Yeah, but if you take a subset A and put it into a function that tells it whether it's in A wouldn't it automaticall give you a 1?

Comment: @user121615: $A$ is not the argument to the function. Let me suggest the following exercise. Suppose $S = \mathbb{R}$. Now draw the graph of the indicator functions $1_A: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ for the following sets: (a) $A = [0,1]$; (b)$A = (0,1)$ ; (c) $A = \{1, 2, 3\}$. Do you see that each set $A$ gets its own graph (or its own function)?

Comment: Okay, so I'm clear -- Char: P(S)(domain) → F(S, {0 -> 1})(range). The domain is our powerset and our range is a set of functions. The powerset P(S) has a set S and the functions F(S -> {0,1}) Have a S as a domain. If I let 'A' be a subset of our powerset 'P(S)', Do I also have to let that same A, the element from the powerset equal 'A'in F(S -> {0,1}) as well? Or does the function assume P(S) and F(S -> {0,1}) operate on different subsets of S -- one for the range and one for the domain. That's where my confusion is coming from